# why we use bool here?

Tags: c, primes

I cannot understand why we use `bool isPrime` here, and what this function does.

```
{
    bool    isPrime;
    int     startingPoint, candidate, last, i;

    startingPoint = 856;
    if ( startingPoint < 2 ) 
    {
    candidate = 2;
    }
    else 
    if ( startingPoint == 2 )
    {
     candidate = 3;
    } 
    else 
    {
    candidate = startingPoint;
    if ( candidate % 2 == 0 )           
    candidate--;
    do 
    {
            isPrime = true;                 
            candidate += 2;                 
            last = sqrt( candidate );       
            for ( i = 3; (i <= last) && isPrime; i += 2 ) 
            {
                if ( (candidate % i) == 0 )
                    isPrime = false;
            }
        } while ( ! isPrime );
    }

    printf( "The next prime after %d is %d. Happy?\n",
           startingPoint, candidate );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i still not understand why we need "(!isPrime) = false" to exit Do loop and how works this exit? i mean, what will give "false" to "isPrime" if     "prime = false; " will skipped if "if ((otv % i) == 0)" ? to exit Do loop , we need (!prime) = false, isnt it?

Comment: so to go thought "while ( ! isPrime );" we need " ! isPrime == false" ? how we can get it? Is "isPrime" as default as false?  or when all "do {} " done we go to "while" automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
isPrime is being used to exit from the for loop & do while loop by conditionally.

1. in For Loop 

    Our goal is to find out the next greater prime number of candidate.

    If we have the 25 as candidate, we are going to execute the for loop upto 3 to 5(sqrt of 25).

    if we found that any number between that value(3 , 5)
         divides the candidate and gave the remaining as 0.
         then the candidate was not prime number.
         So exit the from the for loop by flag setting isPrime to false.
         next time the for loop will not be executed because , 
         for loop condition fails.

    Control moves to while loop and checks condition,
            still we didn't find out the prime number & do while condition
            is true by (!isPrime) where isPrime is false (!false == Yes)
            so while loop again executing from the starting of the loop.


2. in Do while loop

    To exit from the do while loop , 
    the condition should be failed, 
    that means isPrime should be always true for 3, 5 in for loop.

    So for loop will entirely run upto the maximum of last value.

    No chance of setting up the isPrime to false on the for loop.

    so it will exit from the do while loop.
    Otherwise it will never sleep until find out the next prime number.
    it will be infinity.

I hope it will help you to understand the
code sequence & why we are using the isPrime flag on the code sequence.
```

**Code sequence Summary:**

**[What is Prime Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number):**

A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that has no positive divisors other than 1 and itself. A natural number greater than 1 that is not a prime number is called a composite number.

For example, 5 is prime because only 1 and 5 evenly divide it, whereas 6 is composite because it has the divisors 2 and 3 in addition to 1 and 6

```
bool    isPrime;
int     startingPoint, candidate, last, i;

startingPoint = 24;

//If start point less than 2
if ( startingPoint < 2 ) {

    //take candidate as 2
    candidate = 2;
}
//If start point equals 2

else if ( startingPoint == 2 ) {
    //take candidate as 3
    candidate = 3;
}
else {


//if none of the above condition then have startingPoint as candidate

    candidate = startingPoint;
    //candiate 24

    if (candidate % 2 == 0)             /* Test only odd numbers */
        candidate--;//if the candidate is even number then make it to odd number by -1 which will be 23

    do {

        isPrime = true;                 /* Initially we are assuming that the Number 23 is prime number.*/

        candidate += 2;                 /* Bump to the next number(23+2 =25) to test */
        //candidate 25

        last = sqrt( candidate );      
        //last 5


        Everytime we will do process the 'for' loop upto sqrt of the candidate.
        //candidate 25
        //last 5

        So If we found the any number between the 3 to 5 not prime number, then we no need to run the for loop till the end.

        Because we need to find out the nearest next prime number. So no need to waste our CPU usage.

        // Both 3<=5 && isPrime should be true.

        //last 3<=5 && true(we assumed it will be a prime number initially)
        for ( i = 3; (i <= last) && isPrime; i += 2 ) {     
            if ( (candidate % i) == 0 )                       
                isPrime = false;
        //here increase the 3 to 5 by (i+2), So again it will be executed. But third time it will fail the first condition.
        //So go to start of do while loop, and so on it will work
        //Next time candidate will be increased by 2 which will be (25+2) = 27 and failed to find out the prime Number.
        //Next time candidate will be increased by 2 which will be (27+2) = 29 and success 29 is prime number.

        }

    } while ( ! isPrime );// if the condition true then go to "do" statement.
}

printf( "The next prime after %d is %d. Happy?\n",
       startingPoint, candidate );
return 0;
```

Comment: so to go thought "while ( ! isPrime );" we need " ! isPrime == false" ? how we can get it?  Is "isPrime" as default as false?

Comment: or when all "do {} " done we go to "while" automatically ?

Answer (score 1):

The function tells you the next prime after a number that the end-user enters. The `isPrime` variable serves as a Boolean "flag" that lets you pass information about a condition that you find inside a loop to the code that runs outside that loop.

The inner `for` loop tries consecutive odd numbers as divisor candidates. When it finds a divisor, it needs to make the fact that the divisor has been found (and therefore the candidate is not prime) known to the outer `do`/`while` loop by setting the `isPrime` flag to `false`. The outer loop checks that flag, and exists the loop only when it is remains `true` after all candidates in the range `3..sqrt(candidate)` have been exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Rewritten into something more readable:

```
bool isOddNumberPrime(int number) {
    assert(number & 2 != 0);

    int i, limit;

    int limit = sqrt( number );       

    //note that this kind of test is terribly ineffective
    for (i = 3; (i <= limit); i += 2 ) {
        if ( (number % i) == 0 ) {
            return false;
        } 
    }

    return true;
}

int getFirstGreaterPrime(int startingPoint) {   
    int candidate;

    if ( startingPoint < 2 ) {
       return 2;
    }
    else if ( startingPoint == 2 ) {
       return 3;
    }
    else if (candidate % 2 == 0) {
       candidate = startingPoint + 1;
    }
    else {
       candidate = startingPoint + 2;
    }

    //candidate holds a greater odd number

    while (!isOddNumberPrime(candidate)) {
        candidate += 2;                 
    }

    return candidate;
}

void main() {
   int number, nextPrime;

   number = 856;
   nextPrime = getFirstGreaterPrime(number);

   printf( "The next prime after %d is %d. Happy?\n",
       number, nextPrime );
}
```